# Inverse Tangent for Complex Numbers

Tags: integration, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Following thoughts occurred to me after I attempted to integrate $\frac{1}{x^6+1}$.

There's the usual way of splitting the fraction into partial fraction, but I tried something else, that is, factorizing the denominator totally into linear factors. Although that introduced complex numbers, but it is much easier to integrate when you have only linear terms in the denominator. After a lot of grinding and grouping terms, I got a rather elegant result: $$\frac{1}{3}\left(\arctan(x)+\frac{\arctan(\omega x)}{\omega}+\frac{\arctan(\omega^2 x)}{\omega^2}\right)$$
Of course, when evaluated through other means, the answer does not consist of complex numbers; it is: $$\frac{1}{3}\left(\arctan(x)+\frac{1}{2}\arctan(x-\frac{1}{x})+\frac{\sqrt3}{4}\ln\left(\frac{x^2+\sqrt3x+1}{x^2-\sqrt3x+1}\right)\right)$$
This got me thinking of a way to simplify inverse tangent when the argument is complex, so I set out to simplify $\arctan(a+ib)$. I will spare the gory details, but the basic idea is: let the desired output be $c+id$, then shift the arctan, open up $\tan(c+id)$, use the fact that $\tan ix=i\tanh x$. Shuffled things around, and finally, I got a quadratic in $\tan c$, and that's where things got stuck: A quadratic has two roots, which one to take? I took the positive sign in front of $\sqrt D$, $D$ is the discriminant here. Finally, I obtained: $$c=\arctan\left(\frac{a^2+b^2-1+\sqrt{\left(a^2+(b-1)^2)(a^2+(b+1)^2\right)}}{2a}\right)$$ and $$d=\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{a^2+(b+1)^2}{a^2+(b-1)^2}\right)$$
Now, the questions:

1. Is the obtained result for $c$ and $d$ correct? My main point of doubt is the sign in front of the radical. If someone could guide me through that, it would be helpful.(Note: This worked out absolutely fine for the test case of $\arctan (1+i)$)
2. If the result I obtained is not correct, please do describe the correct procedure to me.
3. If previous work has been done on this, a link to that would be useful.

Disclaimer: I am only a high school student. For the context of this question, everything is self-taught,  and I am not aware of advanced techniques.

Comment: For me $d$ is perfect. What I would prefer is to stay with $$c=\frac{1}{2} (\arg (i a-b+1)-\arg (-i a+b+1))$$ in order to avoid the problem you mention.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I verified your result, seems totally fine. But when I calculate $d$, that uses $\tan c$, so the problem crops up again. Unsure of why I got the correct result for  $d$, though.

Comment: We are entering an infinite loop !